# Handling anchor tag in mojolicious

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I am trying to upload a file using mojolicious and then after some altering, I want to download the same file. File Upload part is Ok.But I am unsure how to handle routes for downloading the file.

`Controller`:

```
sub upload{
    my $self=shift;
    my $upload=$self->param('fileName');
    my $file_name=$upload->filename;
    $self->render(file=>"$file_name",
                  filepath=>$filepath
          );
  }
```

I have this in template `upload.html.ep`.

```
<body>
Successfully uploaded file: <%=$file%><br/>
<a href="download/<%= $filepath %>" class="button">
  Download!
</a>
```

Now `a href` is generated here as `a href=download/file/path/foo.txt`. How to handle route for this path?

```
my $r = $self->routes;
# Normal route to controller
$r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');    
$r->post('/upload')->to('example#upload'); #working well 

$r->get('/download/:file')->to('example#download'); # not working
```

I am getting error as:

```
None of these routes could generate a response for your GET request for 
/download/file/path/foo.txt.
```

I thought place-holders works this way.

Comment: If the `$filepath` contains a slash `/` the routing will get confused, because it expects a single argument. Try using the _filename_ without the full path (you shouldn't expose that anyway). It should look something like `http://example.org/download/myfile.txt` where `myfile.txt` is the _filename_. Compare to the route `/product/:id/details` where the `$id` is also not allowed to have a slash as that makes the route matching break. (This is an edjucated guess as I'm not familiar enough with Mojo but if it works I'll write it up as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [wildcard placeholders](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod#Wildcard-placeholders):

```
$r->get('/download/*file')->to('example#download');
```

Comment: and how to get in `sub` means in `sub download{$self->param('here what should i put')}`

Comment: @AruneshSingh `$self->param('file')`.

Comment: It is taking the path as whole `/download/file/path/foo.txt` but I wanted only `/file/path/foo.txt`. should I remove it using `regex` or any other idea

Comment: @AruneshSingh No, `$self->param('file')` should return `file/path/foo.txt` for `/download/file/path/foo.txt` request.